# How to prove the following property of implication?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, provability

The question with which I am struggling is the following,

> **Question.** Let $\Gamma$  be a consistent set of wffs of propositional calculus (see the axioms and rule of inference below). Let $\alpha,\beta$ be two wffs. If $\Gamma\nvdash\alpha$ and $\Gamma\nvdash\beta$, is it possible to have $\Gamma\vdash\alpha\to\beta$?

The axioms and rules of inference are (here $P,Q$ and $S$ are arbitrary formulas),

> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 1.}}\  P\to (Q\to P)$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 2.}}\  (S\to (P\to Q))\to((S\to P)\to (S\to Q))$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 3.}}\  (\neg Q\to\neg P)\to(P\to Q)$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Rule of Inference.}}$ [Modus Ponens](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8i9j2vZHPAhVLn5QKHVpiC0YQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FModus_ponens&usg=AFQjCNGjiX3Tbw5h49jNotuefUM9xvBIDw).

**My Attempt**

I tried by assuming on the contrary that $\Gamma\nvdash\alpha\to\beta$ and then extending $\Gamma$ to a maximal consistent set $\Delta$ such that $\Delta\nvdash\alpha\to\beta$. I have also noted that $\Delta\vdash\alpha$ and $\Delta\nvdash\beta$ as well. But I can't find any contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$, for *suitable* formulas $\alpha, \beta$.

Indeed, since $\Gamma$ is consistent, there exists a formula $\alpha$ such that $\Gamma \not\vdash \alpha$. Take $\beta = \alpha$. Thus, $\Gamma \not\vdash \beta$ but $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$, as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927952/288417) for a derivation in Hilbert system.

---

Note that the statement "if $\Gamma$ is consistent and $\alpha,\beta$ are formulas such that $\Gamma \not\vdash \alpha$ and $\Gamma \not\vdash \beta$, then $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \to \beta$" is false for arbitrary formulas $\alpha, \beta$ and arbitrary $\Gamma$. For instance, if $\alpha, \beta$ are two distinct propositional variables and $\Gamma$ is the empty set of formulas, then $\Gamma$ is consistent, $\Gamma \not\vdash \alpha$ and $\Gamma \not\vdash \beta$ but $\Gamma \not\vdash \alpha \to \beta$.

Comment: What properties of Γ would ensure that for arbitrary formulas $α,β$ that if $Γ⊬α$ and $Γ⊬β$ then $Γ\vdash α→β$ as well?

Comment: I think if $\Gamma$ is maximal consistent then we have the required thing.

Comment: @user170039 - Exactly! Do you have a proof? Hint: if $\Gamma$ is maximally consistent then it is complete (i.e. for every formula $\alpha$, either $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$ or $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \alpha$).

Comment: Yep. I do have a proof. If $\Gamma$ is maximal consistent and $\Gamma\nvdash\alpha$ then we have $\alpha\notin\Gamma$. Hence $\Gamma\cup\{\alpha\}$ is inconsistent. Hence we have $\Gamma\cup\{\alpha\}\vdash\beta$. Applying DT $\Gamma\vdash\alpha\to\beta$.

Comment: @user170039 - Perfect!